# AX in gets strange number from word array

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

i'm trying to sub two arrays to create third one, but when i try to sub them the value the AX register get is completely different than the original.
in the first sub, as you can see, i'm trying to move the number 2082(822 h) to AX but in TD it shows AX get something like 32849(8052 h) . what's wrong??? thanks!!!

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
ARR1   DW 333,20989,3456,2082
ARR2   DW 333,15,5436,2082
ARR3   DW ?
ANSWER DB 'The last digit is: X' ,13,10,'$'
TEN    DW 10


.CODE
     MOV AX,@DATA   ; DS can be written to only through a register
     MOV DS,AX      ; Set DS to point to data segment

     ; Making the first arr3 number

     MOV DI,3
 MOV AX,0
 MOV AX, ARR1[DI]
 SUB AX,ARR2[0]
 MOV ARR3[0], AX
 MOV AX,0
```

Comment: The data type `DW` take 2 bytes of storage, but `MOV AX, ARR1[3]` is using the odd number 3. So you will not read anything meaningful. The offset must be a multiple of 2, in this case `6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each data value `DW` is stored as 2 bytes, with the least significant byte first (little-endian). But you are using an offset of `3` which does not align with the data.

Your data values will appear in memory as

```
ARR1    4D 01 FD 51 80 0D 22 08
...              ^^ ^^
```

By loading from offset `3` register `AX` will receive the value `8051` ( little-endian) which in decimal is  32849.

You should be using an offset of `6` to read the last element in that array. Alternatively (when using 32-bit mode) you can scale the offset with

```
MOV EAX, ARR1[EDI*2]
```

Comment: Maybe be worth noting, for other readers, that `MOV AX, ARR1[3]` is not an array indexing (like it seems to be) but a silly way of writing `MOV AX, [ARR1 + 3]`. That's probably what the OP thought was going on.

Answer (score 1):

> what's wrong?

Each element in your arrays occupy one *word* (because of `DW`). In x86 terminology a word is 16 bits, i.e. 2 bytes.

So the 4th word from `ARR1` would be located at `[ARR1+3*2]`, i.e. `[ARR1+6]`.

---

> TD it shows AX get something like 32094

You're loading the 3rd and 4th bytes after `ARR1`, so let's look at what those contain:

```
DW 333,20989,3456,2082
```

As hex for clarity:

```
DW 014Dh, 51FDh, 0D80h, 0822h
```

As bytes (x86 are little-endian):

```
DB 4Dh,01h,FDh,51h,80h,0Dh,22h,08h
```

So you're loading `AX` with the bytes `51h`,`80h`, i.e. `8051h` (or 32849 in decimal).